# CodeIgniter 3 - configuring log_threshold

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Ok I got confused.

Inside `application/config.php` it says in comments:

```
    | If you have enabled error logging, you can set an error threshold to
| determine what gets logged. Threshold options are:
| You can enable error logging by setting a threshold over zero. The
| threshold determines what gets logged. Threshold options are:
|
|   0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
|   1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
|   2 = Debug Messages
|   3 = Informational Messages
|   4 = All Messages
|
| You can also pass an array with threshold levels to show individual error types
|
|   array(2) = Debug Messages, without Error Messages
```

So if I want to get Error and Debug messages and not any Information messages, do I have to set the threshold

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 2;
```

or

```
$config['log_threshold'] = array(1, 2);
```

Could someone give me some clarification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both would work, simply because informational messages has a value of 3, while the maximum one that you want is 2.

However, if you wanted to log informational and error messages, but *no* debug messages, you'd have to set a value of `array(1, 3)` in order to skip the debug ones.

Comment: then why in comments says `array(2) = Debug Messages, without Error Messages` ? isn't this the same as `$config['log_threshold'] = 2;` ???

Comment: Because it's just impractical to repeat every previous line.

Comment: so either I set `$config['log_threshold'] = 2;`, either `$config['log_threshold'] =  array(1, 2);` or `$config['log_threshold'] =  array(2);`, all have the same result, right ? just to confirm ..

Answer (score 0):

In /application/config/config.php set
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;