# codeigniter logging function not generate message

Tags: codeigniter, error-handling

page show this error in codeigniter project but log file not generate error

its me first experience with logging function
so i do not know how to generate error

```
   A PHP Error was encountered
    Severity: Notice

    Message: Undefined variable: bottomstatus

    Filename: views/template.php

    Line Number: 65

    Backtrace:

    File: D:\xampp\htdocs\timehubzone\application\views\template.php
    Line: 65
    Function: _error_handler
```

codeigniter error status

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
$config['log_path'] = '';
$config['log_file_extension'] = '';
```

Comment: codeigniter have own function generate autometically we just $config['log_threshold'] = 1; set logtreshold bydefault 0 and adujest 1 then generate the error

Comment: in my case this function not work i do not know where is missing any thing

Comment: yes page show Undefined variable: bottomstatus please read this threed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32325471/log-file-in-codeigniter

Comment: The directory where you want the log files to be saved needs to be writable.

Comment: did you look in the logs folder?

Comment: use 777 remotely but 755 worked locally.

Comment: codeigniter already have own log directory path bydefault thanks now i have resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get notices logged too - you've to increase your threshold value

Instead of

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

you simply have to change that to

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 2;
```

> Be aware, this isn't useful for production environments - because your log file will get to big. You will find more information at the [Codeigniter Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html) and at this SO post answered by Narf: [CodeIgniter 3 - configuring log_threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237977/codeigniter-3-configuring-log-threshold)

Comment: it work for me but not generate which url hit according error.just show file name i want to show which url have error